# if, elseif, else statement will not execute correctly

Tags: matlab, if-statement, logical-operators

I am currently working on a piece of code and the `if, elseif, else` statements will not cooperate with me. It is very simple code, most are just constants I've defined:

```
K1 = 0.174532925;
K2 = 0.20943951;

y0 = [0.0 15.2161 0.0 0.0];

ieout = [];

if isempty(ieout)
    if y0(1)>K1
        ieout = [ieout 5];
    elseif  K1>y0(1)>-K1 && y0(2)<0
        ieout = [ieout 1];
    elseif -K1>y0(1)>-K2 && y0(2)<0
        ieout = [ieout 2];
    elseif -K1>y0(1)>-K2 && y0(2)>0
        ieout = [ieout 3];
    elseif K1>y0(1)>-K1 && y0(2)>0
        ieout = [ieout 4];
    end
end
```

Now, my vector `y0` have all `zeroz` except at the second position which is positive, so this means the last `elseif` statement should be executed. This is not the case, instead the statement before the last is executed and my vector `ieout` gets a scalar element `3` instead of `4`.

This confuses me, why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't chain logical operators like `1<y<2`. You have to use `1<y && y<2` So:

```
K1 = 0.174532925;
K2 = 0.20943951;

y0 = [0.0 15.2161 0.0 0.0];

ieout = [];

if isempty(ieout)
    if y0(1)>K1
        ieout = [ieout 5];
    elseif  K1>y0(1) && y0(1)>-K1 && y0(2)<0
        ieout = [ieout 1];
    elseif -K1>y0(1) && y0(1)>-K2 && y0(2)<0
        ieout = [ieout 2];
    elseif -K1>y0(1) && y0(1)>-K2 && y0(2)>0
        ieout = [ieout 3];
    elseif K1>y0(1) && y0(1)>-K1 && y0(2)>0
        ieout = [ieout 4];
    end
end
```

Comment: I see, I reckoned there was something wrong about those, not the same as Python. Thanks!